# The combination of HTTP POST and GET requests + Javascript calling in JAVA?

Tags: java, javascript, html, post, request

Okay, this is going to be hard to explain but here goes nothing:

Lately I've been working a lot with POST and GET requests, but now I want to send a POST/GET request to this site called: http://www.mangareader.net/

The main problem I'm facing is that I want to use the search function of this site. Normally I would send a get request or something like that, but apparently this search function doesn't work that way, it works with some kind of Javascript code? I don't know exactly what it is, but try typing "Elf" in the search bar, and you'll get a drop down list of all the mangas (Japanese comics) with the word "Elf" in them. I want to know how this process is called, and how I can implement it into a Java program. For instance:

Login into a website
- > Send an HTTP post request. Get HTML data back. Process the HTML data. Get the information I need from the HTML source.

Using a search function on a regular site like google.com or bing.com
- > Send get request. Get HTML data back. Process the HTML data. Get the information I need from the HTML source.

Using search function on mangareader.net
- > ??????????

How would I achieve this? A theoretic explanation is enough, but a practical example would be great as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you analyse the javascript that runs when search you get the following:

GET http://www.mangareader.net/actions/search/?q=test&limit=100 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 113ms]

In other words, you can search on the site by a GET-request to

http://www.mangareader.net/actions/search/?q=test&limit=100

Where ?q contains your search word.

Comment: Wow... that is actually pretty great. I'm stuck on one problem though, which is when that drop down list shows up, you can actually click one of the items to go to that manga's link. This is helpful, but I need to know the link too. Is there a possibility of doing this?

Comment: Sorry, no, my bad, I already see how I could get the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This site uses an ajax call to get a | ( pipe symbol ) seperated list from the page

> /actions/search?q=term

It parses this list using string split and then makes it into combobox.

I have little experience with java, but a simple GET request to this page should work
replace **{term}** with your search function.

```
http://www.mangareader.net/actions/search/?q={term}&limit=100
```

You can use chrome network monitor to see if for your self